# It would be selfish OF us or FOR us

Tags: prepositions

I am reading this book, and someone says: it would be selfish OF us to stay here

Could it be “FOR us to stay here”?. Are for and of interchangeable in this case? Because I have heard people using both

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, and both are used in American English, though this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=selfish%20of%20us%2Cselfish%20for%20us&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) shows that "selfish of us" is a lot more common. This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=selfish%20of%20us%2Cselfish%20for%20us&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) shows that "selfish for us" is not used at all in British English.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technical difference. "Selfish for us to do something" is saying that doing something is a selfish action. "Selfish of us to do something" is saying that by doing something we would be selfish.

If you replaced "selfish" with "appropriate", the sentence "It would be appropriate for us to do something" works but "It would be appropriate of us to do something" doesn't work because it is the action that is appropriate, not us.

Also "That would be selfish of us" works, but "That would be selfish for us" does not.

Comment: I don't think "That would be appropriate of us" is used in British English. We don't say. 'How appropriate you are' or 'She is appropriate'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian True. However "That would be appropriate for us" can work.